# In shell, eshell and comint-modes, the cursor moves back one chacacter when I switch buffers

Tags: evil, shell, eshell, comint, cursor

When I'm in a shell and I change buffers, if I switch back to the shell buffer, the cursor has moved back a character and I can't start typing new shell commands until I hit `->` first.

This happens even with: `(setq evil-move-cursor-back nil)`

I'm using evil. This doesn't happen when with `emacs -Q` or in spacemacs, so there must be something wrong with my config, but I don't know what to look for that might be causing it.

Answer (score 3):

> *there must be something wrong with my config, but I don't know what to look for that might be causing it.*

So that's your **question**, in fact: How do I find how my init file caused a problem?

The **answer** is to use the usual *binary search* (*O(logN)*): **Recursively bisect** your init file until you find what introduces the problem.

You can do this by commenting out 1/2 of the file, then 3/4, 7/8,... You can use command `comment-region` to comment-out selected text, and the same command with `C-u` to uncomment it.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that :(

Comment: It's very quick to do. But it does require that you restart Emacs a few times.

Answer (score 2):

It was easier to find than I thought.

This was the culprit `(hiwin-activate)` from [hiwin-mode](https://github.com/tomoya/hiwin-mode)

I opened this issue: https://github.com/yoshida-mediba/hiwin-mode/issues/7

## UPDATE

I switched to https://github.com/mina86/auto-dim-other-buffers.el